# File uploads and moves,returns blank page

Tags: php

This may be something so stupidly simple I'm not seeing it. Doing a file upload & rename, then sending it to a confirmation page. File upload & rename works perfectly. But when the script is finished, I get a blank page and it does not redirect to mypage.php. I suspect the last IF statement. Anyone see what I am missing?

```
<?php
require "db_conn.php";
$ID=$_POST['ID'];

if ($_FILES['wimage']['error'] > 0)
  {
    echo 'Problem: ';
    switch ($_FILES['wimage']['error'])
    {
      case 1:  echo 'File exceeded upload_max_filesize';  break;
      case 2:  echo 'File exceeded max_file_size';  break;
      case 3:  echo 'File only partially uploaded';  break;
      case 4:  echo 'No file uploaded';  break;
    }
    exit;
  }

  // put the file where we'd like it
  $upfile = $SCIMAGEPATHLISTINGS.'/'.$_POST['ID'].'.jpg';

  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['wimage']['tmp_name']))
  {
     if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['wimage']['tmp_name'], $upfile))
     {
        echo 'Problem: Could not move file to destination directory';
        exit;
     }
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Problem: Possible file upload attack. Filename: ';
    echo $_FILES['wimage']['name'];
    exit;
  }

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['wimage']['tmp_name'], $upfile))
{
 header ("Location: mypage.php?ok=add&Address=$ID");
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you enable debugging on your server, either through `var_dump`s here and there or `error_reporting`? Have you tried anything to solve this problem on your own?

Answer (score 0):

See the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) which says

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

In your case there are output before `header()` which may generating error and it may possible that your error reporting is off thus giving empty page

Comment: ok, then how do I get the code to go to mypage.php? The header method is the only way I've ever used.

Comment: Firstly comments those `exit`s, they may be the cause your script terminates before executing your last if

Comment: Commented the exits out. No change in behavior.

Comment: If it is the header issue then this answer will definitely help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/15598695

Comment: Here's what I changed to, same non-result.

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['wimage']['tmp_name'], $upfile))
{
 echo "<script>location.href = 'mypage.php?Address=$ID';</script>";
}

Comment: I have tried various solutions, including the one above and an ob style below, but still a blank page.

ob_start();
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['wimage']['tmp_name'], $upfile)) {
        header("Location: URLPATH/myfile.php?Address=$ID");
        ob_end_flush();
        exit;
    }


No errors generated and no relocation.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution. Got rid of the original else statement and replaced it with my header code. Now it works like I needed it to with no errors. Thank you all for you assistance!

```
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['wimage']['tmp_name']))
{
     if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['wimage']['tmp_name'], $upfile))
     {
        echo 'Problem: Could not move file to destination directory';
     //   exit;
  }
  else 
  {
 echo header ("Location: mypage.php?ok=add&Address=$ID");
  }
}
```

Comment: `echo header ("Location: mypage.php?ok=add&Address=$ID");` that will never work. It will output before header.